# Instagram Send Message API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have implemented the instagram messaging in my app. Using the below method:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram
```

I have given the permissions which are mentioned in the documentation.The permissions are:

> pages_manage_metadata, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_messages

I have requested the advanced access to the permission and got rejected saying the use case is invalid for the **instagram_basic** permission

Can anybody say the purpose of the **instagram_basic** permission along with these permissions for using the send message API for Instagram.

Comment: To authenticate the user and retrieve their basic profile information, including their Instagram username and ID. This data is used to identify the recipient of the message and send the message to that recipient. Can this be the use case for the instagram_basic permission??